# Не правильно работает List::insert()

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Код новичка, поэтому судите по всей строгости, чтобы я сразу ввёл правки. Но не факт что я пойму ваши правки)

Не работает метод List::insert(), а точнее обрывается после вставки нового элемента

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

class Date {
public:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

class List {
public:

    List();
    ~List();

private:

    class Node {
    public:

        Node* pNext;

        Date object;

        Node(int day, int month, int year, Node* pNext = nullptr) {
            this->object.day = day;
            this->object.month = month;
            this->object.year = year;
        }
    };

    int Size;
    Node* head; //Указатель на первый элемент списка

public:

    void append(int day, int month, int year);                  // Добавляет элемент в конец списка
    Date get(int index);                                        // Геттер структуры == элемента класса 
    void set(int day, int month, int year, int index);          // Сеттер структуры == элемента класса
    void create_empty(int value);                               // Создаёт пустой список размером value
    void insert(int day, int month, int year, int index);       // Вставляет новый элемент по индексу index
    void remove(int index);                                     // Удаляет элемент по индексу index
    Date length();                                              // Выводит список
    int GetSize() { return Size; }                              // Геттер размера списка
    void push_front(int day, int month, int year);              // Добавляет элемент в начало списка
};


List::List()
{
    Size = 0;
    head = nullptr;
}


List::~List()
{
}


void List::append(int day, int month, int year) // Работает
{
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = new Node(day, month, year);
        Size++;
    }
    else {
        Node* current = this->head;
        while (current->pNext != nullptr) {
            current = current->pNext;
        }
        current->pNext = new Node(day, month, year);
        Size++;
    }
}


Date List::get(int index) //Работает
{
    int counter = 0;
    Node* current = this->head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (counter == index) {
            return current->object;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
        counter++;
    }
}


void List::set(int day, int month, int year, int index) //Работает
{
    int counter = 0;
    Node* current = this->head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (counter == index) {
            current->object.day = day;
            current->object.month = month;
            current->object.year = year;
        }
        current = current->pNext;
        counter++;
    }
}


void List::create_empty(int value) //Работает
{
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        append(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

void List::push_front(int day, int month, int year) //Работает
{
    head = new Node(day, month, year, head);
    Size++;
}

void List::insert(int day, int month, int year, int index) //Не работает
{
    if (index == 0) {
        push_front(day,month,year);
    }
    else {
        Node* previous = this->head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
            previous = previous->pNext;
        }

        previous->pNext = new Node(day, month, year, previous->pNext);
        Size++;
    }
}


void List::remove(int index) //Работает
{
    Node* previous = this->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
        previous = previous->pNext;
    }

    Node* toDelete = previous->pNext;
    previous->pNext = toDelete->pNext;
    delete toDelete;
    Size--;
}


Date List::length() //Работает
{
    cout << "Кол-во элементов в списке: " << Size << endl;
    int counter = 0;
    Node* current = this->head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        return current->object;
        current = current->pNext;
        counter++;
    }
}


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    List lst;
    Date tmp;
    int value;
    value = 10;




    for (int i = 0; i < lst.GetSize(); i++) {
        tmp = lst.get(i);
        cout << tmp.day << "/" << tmp.month << "/" << tmp.year << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 136-я строка в pastebin, в качестве аргумента передали указатель на еще не созданный объект.

Comment: Не помогло, хотя может я что-то не так пишу

Comment: У вас очень странный алгоритм в ```insert```, вы указываете индекс, но никогда не проверяете выход за пределы памяти. Получается, что возможна такая ситуация когда ```previous->pNext()``` может указывать уже на ```nullptr```, а вы всё продолжаете обращаться к его областям памяти

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за подсказку, исправляю